# Are Video Game Exercise/Sports Suitable for Sports.SE?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Came across this question today:

[Is recommendable to follow the routines of exercises in Play Station?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/796/is-recommendable-to-follow-the-routines-of-exercises-in-play-station)

I think it probably fits into Fitness and Nutrition SE a bit better, but wanted to poll the Sports.SE community to confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Video game sports:** As touched on somewhat in [Are e-sports on topic here?](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67), I believe they belong on [Gaming](http://gaming.stackexchange.com).

**Video game exercises:** We really don't cover exercising at all, with the possible exception of competitive weight-lifting (which hasn't come up yet). Using video games to assist with exercise is a topic for [Fitness](http://fitness.stackexchange.com).

**Conclusion:** No.

**TL;DR:** Ixnay.

Comment: I agree. Should go into the FAQ