# Isn't Chess a sport too?

Tags: discussion, scope

I was browsing through Area 51 and came across this site, and then I saw a separate site for [Chess](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) in the Area 51.

My question is. Is chess considered a sport in general or not?

UPDATE:
After seeing wax's response. I tried to do a bit of research on it, and search for sport. This is what [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport) has to say on Sports

> Sport is generally recognised as activities which are based in
>   physical athleticism or physical dexterity, with the largest major
>   competitions such as the Olympic Games admitting only sports meeting
>   this definition

but later on in the same article in Wikipedia, here is what has been stated about chess and board games

> However, a number of competitive, but non-physical, activities claim
>   recognition as mind sports. The International Olympic Committee
>   (through ARISF) recognises both chess and bridge as bona fide sports,
>   and SportAccord, the international sports federation association,
>   recognises five non-physical sports,[4][5] although limits the amount
>   of mind games which can be admitted as sports

Comment: No, the question is about whether chess is a sport or not? It is only the second part that can be called as offtopic and belonged to meta, that why is there a separate site for Chess in Stack Exchange

Comment: Retracted the close vote, now it's on-topic.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This is a simple question of a game is a sport or not. How is it related to meta? I think one is supposed to ask questions about this website on meta website. Am I right ?

Comment: Updated the question again and removed the part asking why is there a separate website for chess in stack exchange. Now the question is only. Is Chess a sport or not?

Comment: @NaveedButt right, and the definition of sport is highly subjective, so it's either a meta question, or primarily opinion based.

Comment: This question, if not for the purposes of defining the site's scope, is primarily opinion-based. This is why you had been receiving feedback about such...asking this question on the main site is opinion-based.

Comment: It was stubborn attitude. Nobody tried to explain why this is a meta question? I am not going to ask another question on this forum again.

Comment: @NaveedButt The [help center](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) specifically states that questions about what is or is not a sport should not be asked on Sports SE, but gives latitude toward asking as a meta question to help define the site's scope. I may consider hot-dog eating as a sport, but you may not...we have our own opinions (ie, "primarily opinion-based"). Leatherwing also provides good [insight](http://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/434/isnt-chess-a-sport-too#comment978_435).

Answer (score 6):

No. Chess is not a sport for the purposes of this site. This was established pretty decisively on this [meta question](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/q/51/6).

Chess is a board game. And as such questions about it belong on [Board & Card Games](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/).

*[Chess Boxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_boxing)* is on topic though the chess side of it is should be asked on B&CG rather than here because we don't have chess experts here. The boxing side, and the mental preparation to play chess while getting the tar beaten out of you are definitely on topic here. Also, asking chess boxing fandom questions is OK here as long as they are not expert level chess questions (again, few if any chess experts here).

Comment: So you are saying that board games are not sports?

Comment: in that case, what would you say about table games. Like Snooker, Pool, Carom, etc.?

Comment: see my update on the question above.

Comment: @NaveedButt yes, I'm absolutely saying board games are not sports. What you mention are *table games* not board games, and they *do* fall under the classification of what is a sport.

Comment: Have you seen my update in the question? with Wikipedia references and quotes...

Comment: The fact that any organization recognizes Chess as a sport does not automatically force any other organization to do so. If this SE site has determined that a sport must involve some level of physical skill or prowess, they can make that ruling regardless of what Wikipedia or the IOC has determined.

Comment: FYI, since the writing of this post, a [Chess SE](https://chess.stackexchange.com/) has emerged.

Comment: is chess an esport? are esports sports?

Comment: 'established pretty decisively' --> was it?