# Is cheerleading on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

A meta [answer](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/a/56/12582) from a while back speculates about whether cheerleading is on-topic, but doesn't reach a clear answer.

Cheerleading certainly has a strong association with competitive sports and the sports "experience". We allow questions on coaching, refereeing, and organizational aspects of sports (e.g. league management) that go beyond just the players in the field, so it seems that it should be allowed.

Cheerleading, on the other hand, does tend to be non-competitive (e.g. my team's cheerleaders are focused on inspiring our players and entertaining our fans rather than winning points against the other team's cheerleaders or getting them called out), but apparently [competitive cheerleading](https://www.varsity.com/news/what-is-competitive-cheerleading/) is actually a thing.

A quick check on the main page shows [zero results](https://sports.stackexchange.com/search?q=cheerleading) for the string "cheerleading" and also no [cheerleading](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cheerleading) tag.

Questions on cheerleading could cover:

- Techniques (e.g. how to stand on someone else's shoulders)
- Equipment (e.g. specifications for pom-poms)
- Training techniques
- Uniforms (e.g. what must be worn under skirts)
- Recognition, awards, career progressions, scholarships, etc.

Should cheerleading be on-topic?

Comment: You've got a pretty obvious bias showing there. Male cheerleaders tend not to wear skirts...

Answer (score 4):

I'd be fine with cheerleading being on topic.  I'm not confident we have anyone on the site that knows anything about it, though, so we'd have to see if we got anyone who could answer - but I don't think there's any reason for it to be off topic just for a lack of experts.

Cheerleading is definitely a competitive thing, at least to some extent; the question would be if Cheerleading is on topic, is Marching Band also on topic as a result (just as competitive if not more, and just as sports-adjacent).

Comment: I'd say that yes, marching band as a competitive sport would be on-topic (but marching band as a musical performance would not, and there are other sites that cover it).

Comment: Umm, I think you may end up being surprised at just HOW big a thing competitive cheer is....