# Asking a question regarding gambling

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Before posting a question on the main site, I figured I would double-check over here since my question is borderline off-topic.

This would essentially be the question I would post:

> I'm interested in finding the odds of NFL games that were played in the past, as far back as the 1960's.  The NFL doesn't set or keep track of the odds themselves since they are usually maintained by Las Vegas or other gambling websites.  But these gambling websites do not show odds from the past, only upcoming games.
>
> What are some resources where I can find the odds on a game from the past?

Also, there isn't a tag for "History" or "Gambling".

Feedback on posting the question?

Comment: that seems kinda listy. I'd be hesitant on that count and less on the gambling count.

Answer (score 4):

History is, in my opinion, an on topic tag. The saying "history is doomed to repeat itself" is an omen to those who would ignore history; learning how things were done in the past often gives insight to the present.

However, the history of something that is off topic would, by extension, also be off topic. So the real question is whether gambling is on topic in the first place.

There is [not consensus on fantasy sports](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/are-questions-about-fantasy-sports-on-topic), and I would envision gambling as for sure being off topic if it is decided that fantasy sports are off topic.