# The March Madness question

Tags: discussion, scope, on-topic

Referring to this question: https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/520/who-to-pick-for-march-madness

I think this question as posed is not constructive, but is there any way that this question could be rephrased to be on topic for our site? Right now, it is too broad and would attract too many "discussion" type posts.

There is another discussion about [fantasy sports](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/are-questions-about-fantasy-sports-on-topic), if fantasy sports are on topic (which they are not necessarily decided to be yet) then questions about March Madness brackets could be on topic as well, right?

Comment: The question was asked before brackets were even released, which didn't help at all.

Comment: @MichaelMyers - Which allowed it to be closed before anyone could pile on their picks... so that is its sole redeeming quality in my eyes.

Answer (score 5):

I think there is a way to make this question on topic:

> What predictive models exist that have successfully and reliably picked the winners of March Madness?

As the question exists now it's "I can haz picz?" Whereas asking about the existence of a reliable method will be much more welcome.