# What shall we do with questions tagged with the "fantasy" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Fantasy sports is off-topic on Sports SE (re: [assertion](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/should-scoring-for-1st-downs-be-more-widely-accepted-in-fantasy-football#comment17902_10671), [meta post](https://sports.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34/are-questions-about-fantasy-sports-on-topic)).

However, there is a [fantasy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) tag that is promoting questions about fantasy sports (re: [claim 1](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/10671/should-scoring-for-1st-downs-be-more-widely-accepted-in-fantasy-football#comment17903_10671), [claim 2](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/6964/which-wide-receivers-should-i-start-for-week-8#comment14719_6964)).

**What shall we do with questions tagged with the [fantasy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) tag?**

Comment: Joe has added a disclaimer on the [tag:fantasy] tag clarifying that fantasy sports are off-topic. http://sports.stackexchange.com/tags/fantasy/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are three separate questions.

1. Are there *any* questions that would be tagged [fantasy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) that are on-topic? In particular, questions like [this one](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/823/how-does-the-rise-in-popularity-of-fantasy-sports-affect-league-ticket-sales), which aren't about fantasy per se but are about how fantasy sports affect real sports (and as such are a question about real sports, just like "What effects do the rising water levels in the artic have on the baseball season" would be on topic (obviously if written better).  And if so, do we want a [fantasy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) tag for those (maybe [fantasy-real-sports](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy-real-sports) or something?)?
2. What should happen to preexisting questions about fantasy?  Close and delete over time?  Or keep them around (historical lock??)?  In particular, this has some impact on 3. below.
3. Do we want to keep the [fantasy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) tag around, specifically to include a THESE QUESTIONS ARE OFF TOPIC reminder in it?  If so, we have to keep at least one question around.

My opinion:

1. Yes, but I'd rather not have a tag just for them.  I don't think they're common enough to justify their own tag, and I think if they're really on-topic, then another tag is sufficient (like [finances](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/finances) or something).
2. Close and delete over time, excepting one that is kept around for 3.
3. Yes, keep the tag with an off-topic warning.

Comment: My question was going for #2, in which the other two questions would be answered as a result. For #1, if a question isn't predominantly about fantasy, then why keep it tagged as such? I don't think introducing another tag is the answer. For #2, close and keep for historical purposes. For #3, my opinion is no. It "promotes" fantasy questions that are off-topic (at least in two cases...and is reasonable that the interpretation will remain if the tag remains, disclaimer aside).

Comment: Prior to now, there hasn't been an off-topic warning.  I'm just concerned that if we eliminate the tag itself, people will just create it anew.

Comment: I'm not a fan of the historical lock here - I think it's unnecessary, there aren't really any 'great' fantasy questions.  I'd only use it for the purpose of keeping around a single [tag:fantasy] question to persist the tag.

Comment: There are six open fantasy questions (if we exclude the one that isn't predominately about fantasy sports). They aren't "great" fantasy questions, but there is still content (eg, [this one](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/in-fantasy-baseball-should-i-avoid-playing-pitchers-who-are-starting-against-my) about fantasy baseball strategy). Closing as off-topic and letting them be keeps the content around and deters fantasy questions in the future.

Comment: I'm going to defer to you with respect to keeping the tag. About the historical lock, I think [this question](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2462/in-fantasy-baseball-should-i-avoid-playing-pitchers-who-are-starting-against-my) merits it (re: views and votes). Maybe [this one](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/in-fantasy-sports-is-it-proven-that-first-pick-tends-to-win-the-league-most-oft) also...but it's not compelling. Otherwise, the rest can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

The guidance from [network meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/126631/228441) is that

> Questions should not be historically locked if they [...] Have little or no redeeming value.

I'd say that applies to the majority of our questions tagged [fantasy](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantasy) - none of them are great questions, even about fantasy sports. The exceptions in my mind are [1](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/823/how-does-the-rise-in-popularity-of-fantasy-sports-affect-league-ticket-sales), [2](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/5409/do-any-professional-sports-leagues-which-have-drafts-use-a-snake-draft-format) and [3](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/6978/nfl-fantasy-injury-designations-difference-between-questionable-vs-doubtful) which I'd argue are on-topic as their primary point is about real sports, not fantasy sports.

Hence we should close, and then probably delete, the rest. The three on-topic questions can stay around in order to keep the tag alive.

Comment: I think i'm okay with 3, if it's edited to remove the reference to Fantasy (or to at least lessen it).  2 (the snake draft) shouldn't have the fantasy tag in my book.  1 is the only one I'd consider truly to deserve the fantasy tag, and to stay around.

Comment: And what you say about historical lock is exactly what I believe, and I think it's the right reason not to use it here.

Comment: 1 can be retagged with finances. 2 doesn't need the fantasy tag. 3 can be retagged with injuries. About the historical locking, if it is agreed that there is little or no value with the fantasy questions we have, then we can delete them. My take is that some of the questions have value...the one on baseball strategy can be useful for a novice player of fantasy sports...the one on snake draft positioning is useful to encourage fantasy players that positioning isn't an advantage/disadvantage.

Comment: Bottom line is I'm not too bothered on all this - we're not actually being overwhelmed with fantasy sports questions, so let's do some combination of editing, closing, locking and deleting them and move on :-) I'm happy to bow to other's judgments on what the best thing to do with each individual question is. I'll retag those three questions as you suggest.

Comment: Fine with me. I think we mostly agree in how to move forward. What are your thoughts on persisting the [tag:fantasy] tag? I am of the opinion that we eliminate it to stop promoting fantasy questions...but with the off-topic disclaimer recently added, I'm fine with whatever decision is agreed upon.

Comment: No strong views on keeping or deleting the tag.